# With python, I am using a requirements.txt file, how can I find the module specified in that file that installed a particular dependency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

The requirements.txt file is large and investigating it module by module is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

Install pipdeptree in your venv (or a copy where you've installed the requirements.txt files).

Then use the following (substituting your module name for urllib3):

```
$ pipdeptree -r --packages urllib3
urllib3==1.26.15
  - botocore==1.29.125 [requires: urllib3>=1.25.4,<1.27]
    - boto3==1.26.125 [requires: botocore>=1.29.125,<1.30.0]
    - s3transfer==0.6.0 [requires: botocore>=1.12.36,<2.0a.0]
      - boto3==1.26.125 [requires: s3transfer>=0.6.0,<0.7.0]
```

Its a reverse presentation so boto3 is the answer here.